# webpack - var is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a variable which is set in a file called `script.js`:

```
// ...

let foo = {
    bar() {
        return 'done';
    }
}

// ...
```

The 'script.js' file is bundled up by webpack as part of a symfony build.
I then try to access `foo` in an html file script tag:

```html
<script src="build/script.js"></script>
<script>
    foo.bar();
</script>
```

But I get an error that foo is undefined.

I tried to set it on the global namespace, by omitting the `let` tag:

```
// ...

foo = {
    bar() {
        return 'done';
    }
}

// ...
```

I got the same error.

I then tried setting foo as a global var in `script.js` with both `window` and `global`:

```
//...

let foo = {
    bar() {
        return 'done';
    }
}
window.foo = foo;
// global.foo = foo;

//...
```

But I keep getting the error `foo is not defined`.

Basically, my question is: how can I set `foo.bar` in `script.js`, then reference it in a template/html file, after including it?

***EDIT***

I should have stated, but the `script.js` file is to be bundled into a 3rd party site eg

```html
<script src="baz.com/foo"></script>
<script>
    foo.bar();
</script>
```

I was using browserify, but the project requires it to be in webpack now.

Comment: Are you bundling this up with Webpack? Can you take a look at the bundle.js file? I don't understand why would you initiate the script from an html file if you're using webpack to bundle it. Can you try and make a main `app.js` file and import the other needed module into it using `import foo from './script.js';`?

Comment: did you import it? I don't really see an `export const foo` there :)

Comment: @Icepickle I tried `export const foo` - got foo undefined error still

Comment: Is foo undefined because webpack is encapsulating it in an iife?

Comment: @leonsegal can you add a project directory structure? or possible a git link? (It's hard to identify the problem like this, too little data and no ability to try and reproduce the issue)